# Viewshed 2. Understanding of VAT and observer-region relationship table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, visibility

I am having a hard time using new Viewshed 2.
I am trying to join values from result raster with observer-region relationship table (ORRT) using Value from raster and Region from ORRT.

I couldn't find any workflow of connecting VAT and ORRT. Here is my approach:

a. Convert raster to polygon

b. Inner join ORRT using polygon.Region = VAT.Value

c. Calculate area for polygon

d. Create summarize table to show observers with areas

However, I am a bit concerned of using it since there are a couple of issues you can see below.

Concerns:

**1. There are duplicating Values in VAT.**

[image]

**2. There are negative Values in VAT and no corresponding pixels with that Values in the raster.**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The negative values were resulted from the Raster to Polygon conversion operation. This is because the conversion tool overflows when the input raster value is greater than 2 billion (approximately).

I cannot explain such a large value in your Viewshed 2 output raster but maybe it relates to the number of observer points in your input feature class to Viewshed 2.

Comment: It looks like there could be some issues in building the VAT by the viewshed 2 tool. When the raster values are too large (greater than 2 billion), the VAT might not be built correctly. The issue should not happen if your input number of observers is slightly less than what you use in this run.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's a problem in creating the vat when there are between 16 and 32 observers. I think the cell values themselves are correct, though. You can use the identify tool on the output raster to verify that. In any case, we'll take a look at it.

For < 16 observers, you can use arcmap's 'relate' functionality directly with the vat and the orrt to match all observers that are associated with a given region, or vice versa.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  It is great to have you participating here.  In a moment I am going to [edit] your question to [remove your signature](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).  This may seem pedantic but the idea is to keep any distracting information like the names of people out of posts here by restricting that to your [user card](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/59457/jt64?tab=profile), which signs every post you make, and where you are free to include whatever information about yourself that you like.